# Java keyPressed Event stops working after Window Focus was Regained

Tags: java, swing, jframe, keyevent

I have a little Problem with my KeyPressed Event.
If I launch my App everything works fine. If I then Defocus the Window, and later Refocus, the KeyEvent does not fire. After I press "Shift + Tab", It works again.

```
@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
// Prints the keycode
System.out.println("Key-Pressed: " + e.getKeyCode());
}
```

These are just, for showing if the Window is in focus.

```
@Override
public void windowGainedFocus(WindowEvent e) {
System.out.println("Window Focus Gained");            
}

@Override
public void windowLostFocus(WindowEvent e) {
System.out.println("Window Focus Lost");            
}
```

Here a small Video that shows what I described: https://youtu.be/j0VKQKUjJGc

I hope some one can help me with this, thank you in advance.

Comment: A KeyListener only works when a component has focus. If it stops working that means the component you added the listener to no longer has focus. Why do you think you need a KeyListener? Swing was designed to be used with [Key Bindings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html). Key bindings can still work even the the component doesn't have focus.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
public void windowGainedFocus(WindowEvent e) {
    System.out.println("Window Focus Gained");
    // requestFocus on the object with the keyPress listener
    panel.requestFocus();
}
```